# I am using pyinstaller in python 3.4. I get dist and bin directory and .spec file but the file inside dist directory does not contain .exe extension

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using this code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py
```

When i try to run that file on windows it does not run.

Comment: I forgot to mention , I am using pyinstaller on ubuntu

Comment: You can't make it in Ubuntu and run on Windows. You need to make it in the same OS that you want to run it in.

Answer (score 0):

Few things, use cx_freeze for python 3. I have failed with pyinstaller.
Also keep in mind you are supposed to do that via CMD. On CMD do

```
cd dir/to/python/scripts
the command
```